# How to make Flask request.form return ordered dict data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, request.form

I currently have a form on my flask web app that has +- 100 inputs. To request every value in 1 line I use: `f = request.form`. If I print it on my local version, I'll end up with a complete list of all my values in complete order:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('intro1', 'hello'), ('intro2', 'eargr'), ('intro3', 'rferferaf'), ('intro4', 'eragaerg'), ('intro5', 'aergferaf'), ('intro6', 'aerfa'), ('intro7', 'faf'),`('intro8', 'fazfa'), ('intro9', 'f'), ('intro10', 'f'), ('intro11', 'f'), ('intro12', 'ezfzef'),` ('intro13', 'f'), ('liab1', ''), ('liab2', 'hello'), 
    ('liab3', ''), ('liab4', 'nvion'),....
```

If I print it on my live version, it will return it in a complete random order:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('liab43', 'hello'), ('pl33', ''), ('inv3', ''), ('fin5', ''), ('inv10', ''), `('pl44', ''), ('liab46', ''), ('liab17', ''), ('liab49', ''), ('intro10', 'ovov o'), ('fin9', ''), ('pl30', ''), ('pl15', ''), ('liab10', ''), ('pl34', 'hello'), ('pl24', ''), ('intro13', 'nvion'), ('liab31', ''), ('pl39', ''), ('intro3', 'zenfoczoi'), ('liab1', ''), ('inv15', ''), ('pl16', ''), ('liab50', ''), ('intro1', 'hello'), ('intro8', 'connfvo'), ('pl38', ''), ('fin4', ''), ('pl49', ''), ('pl21', ''), ('fin6', ''), ('intro2', 'hefhuze'), ('liab22', ''), ('pl61', ''), ('pl18', ''), ('fin10', ''), ('liab53', ''), ('liab30', ''),`
```

How can I fix this? Because both version are completely the same, no difference. Local version is on Windows and live version on a Debian VPS using nginx & gunicorn.

Comment: Looks like you're using different Python versions locally and on the server? Not sure about `ImmutableMultiDict`s, but dictionaries only became ordered relatively recently (either 3.6 or 3.7 iirc).

Comment: Is this actually causing a problem in your production code, or is it just a curiosity? You should use a list rather than a dict if the order matters.

Comment: > Is this actually causing a problem in your production code, or is it just a curiosity?
Yes it is.
I changed my VPS to 3.8 (which is the same version on my local version) and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you call [`request.form`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.form), Flask return a `ImmutableMultiDict` (immutable dict), but you can also let it return `ImmutableOrderedMultiDict` (ordered immutable dict) if you want the data in order. Just do this:

```
from flask import Flask, Request
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableOrderedMultiDict

class MyRequest(Request):
    """Request subclass to override request parameter storage"""
    parameter_storage_class = ImmutableOrderedMultiDict

class MyFlask(Flask):
    """Flask subclass using the custom request class"""
    request_class = MyRequest

app = MyFlask(__name__)
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the help! But I'm kind of curious, why would it order it locally and not on the live version by default?